# 40kHz signal amplifier with ua741

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I am trying make an amplifier with UA741 to amplify signal from ultrasonic sensor. I tested this circuit with a sinusoidal signal from function generator but this only raised the signal level adding DC component nearly equal to voltage applied in the pin 7 (marked +9v).

[image]

Am I missing something obvious here
[image]

Any better solution to amplification are also welcome.

Comment: what circuit? Where's your schematic?

Comment: Blindly, I assume that you are using single supply only, correct?

Answer (score 4):

You are grossly misusing your op amp. If you haven't done so already, look at the [data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ua741.pdf) and pay attention to Figure 5. Note that at 40 kHz with a +/- 15 volt supply you might hope for +/- 3 volts out, but notice that this is way out on the end of the operating range. Your circuit only uses a single 9 volt supply, so there is simply no reason to think that your 741 will operate successfully.

The answer to your problem is simple: get a different op amp. It needs to be specified for operation at 9 volt supply, and it must be specified for operation at at least 40 kHz.

Comment: Note Figure 7 as well. The open-loop gain of the '741 at 40 kHz is only about 26 dB, which is a voltage ratio of about 20. Figure 5 is related to the slew-rate limitations of the chip's output stage.